# In JS, how do I catch errors thrown by user-defined functions' asynchronous calls?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, error-handling

I'm writing a library that takes user-defined functions. I don't have control over what they do, but I want to catch all errors that they cause.

They might also make asynchronous calls like `setTimeout`, which might throw Errors. I want to catch those errors too.

For example—

```
// Suppose this is passed as an argument to the module
var userFunction = function() {
    setTimeout(function() { throw Error("fail") }, 200);
}

// This is module code
try {
    userFunction();
} catch (e) {
    console.log("Caught error");
}
```

—fails with an error and prints a stack trace. The `catch` doesn't trigger.

I can see how this happens: The error is thrown from the function passed to `setTimeout`, which is called after the `try`-`catch` has passed, in a different context.

How do I work with that? Is it even possible?

If given a function that might call `setTimeout` or other asynchronous processes within it, how can I catch errors they might throw?

Comment: You need to `return` them and handle it in *callback* function, just like `node.js` does

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.onerror` to catch all error

```js
try {
    setTimeout(function() { throw Error("fail") }, 2000);
} catch (e) {
    console.log("Caught");
}

window.onerror = function (){
  document.body.innerHTML = "Test";
}
```

or you can use `try catch` inside async method

```
setTimeout(function() {
       try {
          throw Error("fail");
       } catch (e) {
        console.log("Caught");
    }
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: The first catches *all errors*; also those from my code and all libraries I'm using, with no way to distinguish them, which would cause more problems than it fixes. The second means I need to tell my library's users to wrap every async call they make in a try-catch, which results in lots of repetition that makes a mess of their functions.

Comment: @Anko you can use Promise instead of using callback. there you can catch the exception.

Comment: If it doesn't involve changing the passed-in user functions, I'd appreciate an explanation of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promises.

With jQuery, something like:

```
var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();

setTimeout(function() {
  dfd.reject("some error msg");
}, 1000);

$.then(dfd.promise()).then(function() {
//blank, this is success callback
}, function(msg) {
//throw your error
});
```

Full doc: https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

EDIT: can use any Promise implementation. Such as kriswowal/q
https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: That involves adding jQuery as a dependency for my library and requiring users to also have jQuery as a dependency so they can pass in appropriately formatted functions. Is there no way to do this in plain JS?

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery. I just used it in the example.You can implement your own Promise library. Discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422021/how-do-promises-work-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include jQuery. You can use javascripts built in Promise object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/prototype

you have:

```
y = x;
```

x returns a promise:

```
function() {
    ...
    return promise;
}
```

All of the asynchronous calls in x are layered:

x is last async handler:

```
x = function () {
    ...
    // a is second to last async success handler etc..
    var j = new Promise (a);

    j.then(function() {
        // a returned resolve
        if (some successful condition) {
            resolve(what ever arguments you want to pass y);
        } else {
           reject(what ever arguments you want to pass y);
        },
        function (e) {
            // error returned by a
            reject(e);
        }
    );
    return j;
};
```

then you can do:

```
y.then(function() {},
    function() {
        console.log("Caught");
    }
);
```